# take the DRAM performance of the processes into consideration when scheduling

Tags: linux, kernel, memory, scheduling

The CFS scheduler in Linux schedules the processes based on the virtual runtime of CPU.

But, the DRAM memory is the bottleneck in most of the emerging domains. Why not take the DRAM performance of the processes into consideration when choosing the next process?

Could anyone please give an explanation?

Answer (score 1):

If a process is doing a lot of memory IO, then that will translate into using a lot of cpu time, so the scheduler *will* account for it, indirectly.

Comment: I don't think the intensive memory I/O operations must lead to the busy of CPU. For example,  http://superuser.com/questions/78362/what-is-the-relationship-between-cpu-usage-and-ram

Comment: @BeileiSun, I have no idea why you reference that question.  You can't access the ram without running on the cpu, so heavy ram use implies heavy cpu use.  Well, with the exception of hardware direct memory access for IO anyhow.

Comment: Thank you. I agree with you that "You can't access the ram without running on the cpu", but heavy ram use doesn't have to imply heavy cpu use. For example, given a block of memory M, program A adds up all the elements of M, program B calculate the product of the elements of M. The cpu load when executing A is lighter than that of B. In another case, given a cpu load L, programm A adds up the elements of a block of memory M, and program B calculate the product of elements of a block of memory m. The size of M is lager than that of m. So, the ram use and the cpu use are not necessary correlated.

Comment: @BeileiSun, heavy cpu usage does not imply heavy ram usage, but the reverse *is* true.  This is because the cpu can be busy with things other than accessing ram, but you can not be busily accessing ram without using the cpu.

Comment: thank you. I agree with you that "you can not be busily accessing ram without using the cpu", but What if program A and Program B have similar cpu usages, but different memory usages and have different influences on the performance of DRAM memory, for example, the row-buffer? which process should be executed firstly?

Comment: @BeileiSun, (n)either.  It doesn't really matter whether one is using only the cpu and the other is using the cpu and ram; both need the cpu so that is the only thing that matters to the scheduler.

Comment: but different tasks have different influences on the DRAM, which may be the bottleneck of the system. And this may affect the throughput of the system...

Comment: @BeileiSun, yes, and if it is, then whatever task is heavily using it will *also* be heavily using the cpu, which the scheduler takes into account.